# Polar Coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I dont really know how to go about this question. I know that the area is

$$\int_\alpha^\beta \frac12 r^2\, d\theta $$

The question is to find the area of the shaded region.

[image]

Comment: Well for starters, what do you think $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be?

Comment: 0 to 2pi? I think...

Comment: The formula you have will not necessarily work in this case, because your region is bounded by two different polar curves. (You have the big circle centered at $A$, and the little circle centered at the origin.)

Comment: We are all having some trouble solving this problem. It is quite involved for our level of Calc 2. This must be a very basic question for you. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Not at all, and I am not trying to suggest that it is basic, but I am trying to see if I can guide you to a solution by invoking what you may have learned from your class. As the region that is bounded by two curves, you'll need to to know where these two curves intersect. Do you know how to find the point(s) of intersection(s)?

Comment: No, I don't think we do. We did a similar example in class, but we still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Here are some link you should consult: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obo7QAvaxSU, 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx (Scroll down a bit for the area between two polar curves.)

Comment: Thank you very much! We appreciate it very, very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785876/area-and-polar-coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read through the links I left on the comments, you should see that the area that's trapped between two polar curves should be:

$$\int_{\alpha}^\beta \frac12 r^2_{out} d\theta - \int_{\alpha}^\beta \frac12 r^2_{in} d\theta$$

Or more compactly,

$$\frac12  \int_{\alpha}^\beta (r^2_{out} -  r^2_{in}) d\theta.$$

Note: This formula should remind you of the formula you learned for finding area between two functions.

$r_{out}$ corresponds to the curve that is further out, further away from the origin. (Remember $r$ represents the distance from the origin.)

$r_{in}$ represents the curve that is closer to the origin, closer to the origin.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ represent the angle (in polar coordinates) of the intersection points of the two curves. To find $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you need to set the two curves in question and solve for $\theta$.

Let me know if you need more help. I can update this post with more details if needed.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much!